# AES encrypt with openssl decrypt using java

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, base64, aes

I have to encrypt an xml file using openssl command line or a C api. The output shall be Base64.

A java programm will be used for decrypting. This programm is provided by the customer and cannot be changed (they are using this code for legacy applications). As you can see in the code below the customer provides a passphrase so the key will be generated using the SecretKeySpec method.

Java code:

```
// Passphrase
private static final byte[] pass = new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };


public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(pass, "AES");
    return key;
}
```

I have tested several commands like:

```
    openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -a -salt -in file.xml -out file_enc.xml -pass pass:123456789012345
    openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -a -nosalt -in file.xml -out file_enc.xml -pass pass:123456789012345
```

But non of the given outputs is successfuly decrypted using java. For testing purposes I used the given java code for encrypting and the result is of course different than the one from openssl.

Is there a way to use openssl C api or command line to encrypt data so it could be successful decrypted using the given java code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java's `SecretKeySpec` uses the password ASCII bytes directly as key bytes, while OpenSSL's `-pass pass:...` method **derives** a key from the password using a [key derivation function](https://openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) to transform the password into a key in a secure fashion.  You can either try to do the same key derivation in Java (which you probably cannot if I interpret your question correctly), or use OpenSSL's `-K` option to pass in a key (as hex bytes!) instead of a password.

You can find out how [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55884564/2873507).

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit. I was struggling with the same problem. I was able to decrypt from Java an AES-128 encrypted message using the following settings.

I used `openssl` to encrypt the data:

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-ecb -in data.txt -out crypted-aes.data -K 50645367566B59703373367639792442
```

As @Daniel suggested, the game changer is to use the `-K` property. The Java configuration that let us to decrypt the generated file is the following:

```
final byte[] aesKey = "PdSgVkYp3s6v9y$B".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final SecretKeySpec aesKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
Path path = Paths.get("src/test/resources/crypted-aes.data");
final byte[] cryptedData = Files.readAllBytes(path);
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKeySpec);
final byte[] decryptedMsg = cipher.doFinal(cryptedData);
```

The magic happens when the hex key `50645367566B59703373367639792442`, its `String` representation `"PdSgVkYp3s6v9y$B"`, and the `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` align together.